# Laravel database not really clear

Tags: php, laravel

I have small problems with queries in Laravel. I have that file in project/app/file.php, and inside of file I have something like this:

```
class Trip extends Model implements TranslatableInterface
{
    use Translatable;
    use Concerns\HasMeta;
    use Concerns\HasActionLinks;

    protected $guarded = [
        'id'
    ];

    const EDIT_PATH = 'extranet/trips';

    /**
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'trips';

    protected static $translatable = [];

    /**
     *
     * @param  mixed $query
     * @param  array $filters
     * @return void
     */

}
```

How can I query this `protected $table = 'trips';`?

blade example:

```
@foreach($trips as $k => $trip)
    <div class="list-group-item planner">
        @include('components.scratchpad_trip')
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**Edit:**

Finally I found the controller.
What to write to select title where 'Amsterdam'?

```
 $trips = $this->getTrips();
 $results = $this->getCombinations();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Read about Laravel Eloquent basics](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent). In your case you can write `$trips = Trip::all()` if you want to select all trips.

Comment: The problem is Where to put this $trips = Trip::all()

Comment: You need to put it into your controller. Method that is responsible for returning your blade view should read $trips and pass this variable into the view.

Comment: @Rade Spend a little time going through the Laravel documentation. It seems you’ve jumped in feet first and now spamming Stack Overflow with simple, easily-answerable questions.